# Where should I learn shaders as a vulkan user?

Tags: shader

I have no prior experience with any other graphics low level libraries and I have barely any clue how shaders work, any book related to shadings is bloated with opengl code and is demoralizing.

Comment: Is there some reason why you can't simply learn what that "bloated" "opengl code" is doing? Learning Vulkan without any graphics knowledge is a Herculean task; better to start with an API that has training wheels.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you should begin with classic opengl shaders in a more friendly enviroment. [ShaderToy](https://www.shadertoy.com/) is a great community where you'll find tons of tutorials, code examples, masterpieces and great experts that comment everyday.